# How to Pivot with Concat SQL Server Query?

Tags: sql-server-2016

please I want some help to choose from the following 3 tables
(I Normalise My database where each column from these 3 columns is in a different table)

Customer     |   type            |     company
---------    |    ----------     |    -----------
John         |    Benz           |     Mercedes
Mark         |    C200           |     Mercedes
Judy         |    Lancer         |     Mitsubishi
John         |    Corolla        |     Toyota
John         |    Galant         |     Mitsubishi

I want the Results as

Customer     |  type1  | type2         |    type3      |  Others
-------      |  ----   |  -----        |      -----    |     -------
John         |  Benz   |  Corolla      | [Empty String]|    Galant
Mark         |  C200   | [Empty String]| [Empty String]|    [Empty String]

So, I want to pivot type and select specific values from it where company equals specific value; then Concat the other type values where the company is not equal my selection as others.

Please, anyone can help me to reach that approach,
Thanks in Advance.

ur.com/zkvf6.png